# Understanding JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript

This line is at the top of a JavaScript file in a project at school.   Can someone tell me what exactly it does?

```
var Tele = { 'Forms': {}, 'Form': {} };
```

It is then followed with three functions like this that all contain more functions as exampled below.
`FormsView.js`

```
Tele.Forms.View = new function (){
    this.SetRequestTitle = function (title) {
    if (el.length == 0) {
        setTimeout(function () { Tele.Forms.View.SetRequestTitle(title); }, 100);
        return;
    }
    $('#FormTitleBarSubMenuText').html(title);
        document.title = title;
    };
    ....
    ....
};
```

Then there is a second JavaScript file `FormView.js` that only contains this

```
Tele.Form.View = new function () {
    this.Initialize = function (data) {
        Tele.Forms.View.SetRequestTitle('Approval Request');
    };
};
```

I am new to JavaScript and scripting in general so I am just trying to figure out how things work. 
I understand what is happening inside the functions, just not what is tying it all together. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line simply declares a variable:

```
var Tele; // Declare a variable with the identifier Tele
```

And assigns an object literal to it:

```
Tele = {} // Empty object literal
```

The object literal has 2 properties, `Forms` and `Form`, the value of each of which is another object literal:

```
Tele = { 'Forms': {}, 'Form': {} } // Object literal with 2 properties
```

Later on, these properties are referred to, and further properties are added to their values (their values are object literals, so you can add properties to them as follows):

```
Tele.Form.View = new function () { // Add a View property to Tele.Form
    // ...
};
```

Comment: In your last sentence, *"their values are object literals"*, I'm not seeing the object literals you're referring to.

Comment: @CrazyTrain - `Tele.Form` and `Tele.Forms` are object literals.

Comment: Oh, ok, your sentence sounds to me like you're talking about the values added to the objects referenced by `Forms` and `Form`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var Tele = { 'Forms': {}, 'Form': {} };
```

This declares a `Tele` object with two empty objects inside (`Forms` and `Form`). The other two snippets assign properties to those objects (`Tele.Forms.View` and `Tele.Form.View`).

Answer (score 0):

That is a JavaScript object. 
 It contained two properties **Forms** and **Form** that are currently empty when created.

To the first property, **Forms**, another property is assigned to it, which is the function (the function is usually called a closure). 
To the second property, **Form**, another property is assigned to it as well, which is also a function. 
To call out the first function, you simply call

```
Tele.Forms.View();
```

and to call the second,

```
Tele.Form.View();
```

Hope the explanation is clear and it helps.

Comment: Neither `.View` property references a function.

Comment: @CrazyTrain, in the layman's language, .View is assigned (aka references) a function; both mean the same in this case.

Comment: No, I'm not talking semantics. I mean that the `View` properties reference objects which are not function objects. If you look at the assignment, what is being assigned is the result of invoking the anonymous function using the `new` operator.

Comment: You are right; I didn't notice the `new` keyword; nice catch :)